# Not able to call svgdotjs rect method in typescript

Tags: javascript, c#, typescript, svg.js

I am trying to use [Svgdotjs](https://svgjs.com/docs/3.0/elements/) version 3.0.2 with typescript in order to draw a simple rectangle on the screen, but the typescript definition file is missing the rect method.

I tried following the guide from the documentation but no matter what I try there appear to be missing methods in the typings file.

```
/// <reference path="../../../node_modules/@svgdotjs/svg.js/svg.js.d.ts"/>
import * as svgjs from "@svgdotjs/svg.js"

var draw = svgjs.SVG('stock-location-svg').size(300, 300);
var rect = draw.rect(90, 100).fill('#f06');
```

but the method in draw.rect() (neither line or ellipse or circle [link](https://svgjs.com/docs/3.0/elements/)) is not found. Can someone guide me to find the solution on how to import the svgdotjs module correctly in typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a new svg document you call `svgjs.SVG()`, then you can add it to any node you like with `addTo('#stock-location-svg')`

```
/// <reference path="../../../node_modules/@svgdotjs/svg.js/svg.js.d.ts"/>
import * as svgjs from "@svgdotjs/svg.js"

var draw = svgjs.SVG().addTo('stock-location-svg').size(300, 300);
var rect = draw.rect(90, 100).fill('#f06');
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but this doesn't yet solve my problem. I should have added into my question that the svg.js file was installed using Node.js package manager. This means that there must be an alternative way to add the file because the above code leads to errors for other packages that we are already using. Do you know the correct way to add the svgjs module into typescript?

Comment: No, thats the correct way of using this package. Which other packages are you talking about?

Comment: Do you still have this in your html page?  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@svgdotjs/svg.js@3.0/dist/svg.min.js"></script>
I forgot to remove it when migrating to type script and this was my issue

Answer (score 2):

That's how I use svg.js 3.0 with typescript

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SVG, Svg } from "@svgdotjs/svg.js"   //v 3.0

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  draw: Svg

  ngOnInit() {
    this.draw = SVG().addTo('#canvas').viewbox(0, 0, 300, 140)
    let rect = this.draw.rect(90, 100).fill('#f06');
  }
}
```